# ffmpeg php get frame / image after half time of the video or after 40 seconds

Tags: php, ffmpeg

hello all i am having this code in my php and i want to get an image after 50% of the duration of the video and also get the duration of the video in a variable i have installed ffmpeg in my php and computer

the page has following code

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
        //ececute ffmpeg generate mp4
        exec('ffmpeg -i '.$uploadfile.' -f mp4 -s 896x504 '.$new_flv.'');
        //execute ffmpeg and create thumb
        exec('ffmpeg  -i '.$uploadfile.' -f mjpeg -vframes 71 -s 768x432 -an '.$new_image_path.'');
```

i want an image after 50% of the duration of the video and also store the video duration in a variable

please give me  some suggestions i am stuck over here

Answer (score 1):

> First you need to get the video duration in second
>   and then you need to multiply total second to 0.5 to get the half.

**Try this one:**

```
$total_sec = exec("ffprobe -loglevel error -show_streams inputFile.mp4 | grep duration | cut -f2 -d=");
$total_half_sec = $total_sec * 0.5;
exec("ffmpeg  -i source.mp4 -f mjpeg -vframes $total_half_sec -s 768x432 -an destination.jpg");
```

For more info here https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html

Comment: You can get rid of `grep` and `cut`: `ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 input` (format duration) or `ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 input` (video stream duration).

Comment: Also, it should be `-vframes 1` for a single frame output, and `-ss $total_half_sec` for the position. Placing `-ss` before the input can be much faster.

Comment: i think i dont have ffprobe please tell me where to get this

Comment: If you have ffmpeg installed it means u also has ffprobe because it is a package check the path of ffmpeg installation u can find there